# pop by index in for loop leaves even indices

Tags: python-3.x

Apologies if this has already been asked before but I cannot find anything similar.

In python I had a need to pop some items to exhaust a list.

I wrote the following to get through some logic and I do not understand what is going on.

I would expect a for loop to iterate each item in the list and pop each item accordingly.

However, when I run the following it only pops the `odd` indices: `[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]` and the `even` ones remain `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]`

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
for code in l:    
    l.pop(l.index(code))
print(l) # [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
```

I managed to get the job done by using a `while` loop:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
while l:
    for code in l:    
        l.pop(l.index(code))
print(l) # []
```

Why does the `for` loop only pop odd indices in this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for item in list` command creates a temporary list of indices (could have had step size as well) which remains static and cannot be changed during the loop execution in Python. Thus,  `indices = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]` permanently stays. When you iterate over the remaining elements after popping in each iteration, though the list completely changes, the indices don't change.

You get it done using the `while`  loop because it iteratively works until the complete list is emptied. The values after individual iterations of the while loop shown below confirm that every for loop only removes odd elements.

`[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
[4, 8]
[8]
[]`

Python won't consider the changes made in the value which it iterates over, while in the `for` loop.

Comment: Is there a way to do it with a for loop?